# C#, design classes to be scalable

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I'm creating an inventory management system, in which the program needs to handle a lot of different equipment, with the possibility for the product owner to increase the selection, without having to change the code.
Some of the products that might need to be included in the application is:

- Transistors
- Wires
- Drones
- RaspberryPie
- Chargers
- 360 degree camera

So far the only solution I've been able to come up with is:
[image]

But right off the bat I see a lot of problems, mainly what if product owner wants to add a 360 degree camera? He would need to physically edit the codebase in order to create that item, also the serial number property repeats itself, which I don't think is optimal.

My first thoughts was just having an Item model, that included all the properties. But that seems like a waste of attributes?
My second thought was using the strategy pattern, but I have a hard time picturing how I can apply it to this diagram.

My question is, how do I make this scalable?

Comment: just have item, Order quantities of Item

Comment: Forget about the code for a minute. Think about how this information is going to be stored, most sensibly in a database. How would you structure that data?

Comment: I highly suggest you to take some C# tutorials. There are quite a few online, and most of them will explain to you how to make such a management system quite early on.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to encode business rules into the type system. You might find this article enlightening: [Wizards and Warriors, part 5](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of excellent answers. To put these into something concrete to visualize here's a thought.

Since this is inventory management, like @ewan said, the SKU is your GUID or good place to start.  Those attributes that are common to all items regardless of what they are would go in this class i.e. Item

- SKU
- Name
- InStockQty
- Manufacturer
- ManufacturerPartNumber
- PackageSize (h x w x l)
- Cost
- CategoryId

Next, you need to be able to add additional properties dynamically.  Instead of looking to create classes to represent each object what about using classes that represent these attributes associated with a specific item.  You will also want to control the types of the attributes so it does not become unmanageable.  This becomes more of a exercise in relational data modeling vs. OOD since it is likely that the persistence of the objects will be more important that the actual modeling of them due to the application scope you have identified.

With just these items in mind you can start coming up with a design:

**Item** (has properties identified above)

- Has a hashtable of ItemAttribute 0-n

**ItemAttribute** (Represents one attribute associated with a specific item)

- id
- attributeId
- value

**Attribute**

- id
- name (length, serialNumber, color, size)
- DataType (int, string, double, etc.)
- description
- Limit (How many can an ItemAttribute contain)

With this type of approach, you are adding attributes for new items instead of redesigning your model.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't represent the actual product types as separate classes, since (as you notice) this would require you to add new code for every new product. The strategy pattern will not help here.

Just create a class/entity representing a product type with fields for description and ID. Drones of different sizes would almost certainly have to be treated as separate product types since they will have different prices and take up different amount of space. Same with different lengths of wire.

Then you have instances of each product type, i.e. the actual items. In the case of serial numbers, they will only be unique for a given product type, so you need both a unique ID per item and an optional serial number field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've figured it out. Sorry it took so long to mark as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A key concept here is Stock Keeping Unit or SKU. Essentially this is an ItemId, but the breakdown may surprise you!

Take for example a Dress. You buy 100 dresses from a wholesaler to sell, you wouldn't have a single Id, "SuperDress". The id would include the colour, style and perhaps even the event you bought them for.

```
SuperDress_L_Green_SummerSale
SuperDress_M_Green_SummerSale
SuperDress_S_Green_SummerSale
SuperDress_L_Blue
```

etc

you know you got the SummerSale dresses from a different supplier at a reduced cost, they need to be accounted for differently. You need to know when you are out of Blue ones and that L ones take up more space. So all these things are part of the SKU

Having a detailed ID like this allows you to avoid adding new columns to your database to record item specific identifiers such as your drone size, Pi Model etc

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you phrase it, the core of your question is how you can expand an application without having to touch its source code. The basic answer is that you can't.

You can't write your code expecting specific fields before they even exist. That's not how it works.

> My first thoughts was just having an Item model, that included all the properties. But that seems like a waste of attributes?

Yes, it is a waste of attributes. It's also the only way you're going to get this to work the way you expect it to - without developing an entirely new framework altogether that abstracts the class structuring into an application of its own.

Because in this "all in one table" scenario, you're not expanding your application, you're adding *data* to the system. *Any* item is just a new data entry, and does not require any changes to the database schema.

But this comes at the cost of all items being treated the same, i.e. no customized forms that only show the relevant fields for the chosen item type, or no automatic reminder/validation that certain items require a serial number whereas others don't.

> My second thought was using the strategy pattern, but I have a hard time picturing how I can apply it to this diagram.

The strategy pattern allows for the dynamic *selection* of strategies, but it does not entail the dynamic *development* of new strategies without touching the source code. The same argument as before applies: who is going to be creating your patterns for you, if not by expanding the application and thus touching the source code?

> He would need to physically edit the codebase in order to create that item, also the serial number property repeats itself, which I don't think is optimal.

As an aside, not related to the main question in focus:

Just because two things look alike does not inherently mean that they are the same thing. For example, if *some* items have a serial numbers and others do no, it would be a mistake to put the serial number on the `Item` class.

Ask yourself if you *really* need these two serial numbers to have a shared origin. Is there any logic that needs to be able to polymorphically access any of the serial numbers?

If so, and you're still using inheritance (which you might not be anymore given the main question you asked), then you could maybe look into an intermediary `ItemWithSerialNumber` (name to be improved) class that extends `Item` to suit that need. Then, all items with serial numbers derive from `ItemWithSerialNumber`, and the ones without a serial number derive from `Item`.

But this is just general advice that doesn't particularly take into account that you might not want to be using inheritance here to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Some people think that the idea behind classes and subclasses is to (directly) model real world objects — it isn't.  Those in this camp tend to think that a class per real-world kind (of items we want to model) is necessary — but it isn't.

Modeling real world items in the computer system is abstraction.  Sometimes all we need to model is an ID, and perhaps some other data relevant to the automation we're trying to offer the customer — certainly not trying to model every detail of real world items, but just enough to make the automation we are providing do what we want it to do (like counting widgets for inventory, where many details of the widget are not important).

We model with purpose: we abstract to leave only details relevant to the purpose.  So, first, understand the purpose of the automation being provided, then model what is necessary for that purpose (and don't expend effort modeling things that don't apply to the automation software's purpose, YAGNI).

Sometimes all we need to model many real world items are many objects, not many classes.  This should be your first "goto": objects, not classes.  Only when we need to model common behaviors and also specialized behaviors (while sharing those common behaviors) should we consider classes (and subclasses).

Many languages cannot create new classes at runtime, only during development — but we can easily create new objects at runtime: yet another reason the first goto should be objects not classes.  (Still, some languages do support class creation at runtime!)

The purpose of classes and subclasses is to allow construction of systems sharing related state and behavior, while also specializing state and behavior where needed — in other words, the purpose of classes and subclasses is for the programmer to organize their code in a DRY manner.  The system as whole then models the state and behavior of the useful abstractions of real world items (useful to the automation's service to its consumers).

Answer (score 0):

Subclasses and/or inheritance will not be very helpful in this scenario. First you need item.Categories to be a set (an item can be in multiple categories). And you need item to have a set of key-value pairs so you can slap a serial nunber and/or a length and/or whatever on it. Then all items will still be the same yet searchable for any combination of properties.

Mapping that sensibly to a relational data model so you can query effectively will be another challenge.